# Search data in DataGridView using FilterDataRow VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, search, datagridview, datagridviewcolumn

```
    DV = New DataView(ds.Tables("CustomerList"))
    FlxCustomerList.DataSource = ds.Tables("CustomerList").DefaultView 
    myDataTable = CType(FlxCustomerList.DataSource, DataView).ToTable                 
    drToAdd = myDataTable.NewRow()
    drToAdd("Customer Account") = ""
    drToAdd("Customer Name") = "" 
    drToAdd("Customer Group") = "" 
    drToAdd("City") = ""
    drToAdd("Mobile No") = ""
    drToAdd("Status") = ""
    myDataTable.Rows.InsertAt(drToAdd, 0)
    myDataTable.AcceptChanges()
    FlxCustomerList.DataSource = myDataTable.DefaultView
    For Each dtrow As DataGridViewRow In FlxCustomerList.Rows
        If dtrow.Index = 0 Then
            dtrow.Frozen = True
        Else
            dtrow.ReadOnly = True
        End If
    Next
```

To achieve the search in `Datagridview` functionality, I'm getting the first row by this, on search enter, key-down function call this

```
CustomerAccountFilterStr = CStr(Me.DataGridView1.Rows(0).Cells("CustomerAccount").Value)
sStr = sStr & " [Customer Account] like '%" & CustomerAccountFilterStr & "%'"
ds.Tables("CustAcc").DefaultView.RowFilter = sStr
```

This is how I binding Data to DataGridView

```
myDataView.RowFilter = sStr
FlxCustomerList.DataSource = myDataView
```

And Then The `DataGridView` which is bound to the `DefaultView` of DataSet. I froze the first row but now, couldn't understand how to put back filtered values from the second-row onwards to the grid.

[image]

The example output should resemble like below.

[image: this]

I'm stuck to implement this functionality. please guide How to implement this functionality?

Comment: You need to first clearly state, what are you trying to achieve - I guess you're trying to use the first line of `DataGridView` as a row for column filters? Getting data from that row and cells is the same process as getting it from the rest of the grid, i.e. `CustomerGroupFilterStr = CStr(Me.DataGridView1.Rows(0).Cells("CustomerGroup").Value)`. As a side note, however weak is your question, it's scary how poor are some of the StackOverflow moderators these days...

Comment: Nobody can respond, while the post is in "Closed" status. A really poor job of a moderator, marking it as Closed. In theory, you can edit your post, the moderator will review it and open it again. In reality this might not happen :-(. So try to update the question, try to show some code you have. I'll have a look at it. My favourite way to apply column filters is to create `ToolStrip` above the `DataGridView` and fill it with `TextBox`es, `ComboBox`es or such and set their `width` to the witdth of corrensponding columns.

Comment: I upvoted and it didn't help, I new it doesn't work that way. The moderator *should* open the question again once you edit it. You should be able to add stuff, like placing a clear question in the beginning and some of your code so that we can elaborate it.

Comment: @Oak_3260548 Check the statement...

Comment: You need to add a field name, that you want to filter, i.e. (modify as per your column name): `ds.Tables("CustAcc").DefaultView.RowFilter = " MyColumn = " & CustomerAccountFilterStr`. However, under common circumstances, I would filter server-side, not client-side. So I would rather apply the condition in the SQL query, rather than `RowFilter`.

Comment: @Oak_3260548 but how to append filter data in datagridview from 2nd row onwards....?

Comment: Your edit 2 doesn't cut it for reopening it. Start your question with text instead of figure. I really have no clue what to look for if you don't tell me in the first paragraph. Keep in mind you that you have to take me on a journey first to finish the riddle ... ;-) End of Review.